# Problems with borders and a fluid layout

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a fluid webpage with borders around it but the moment I used css to make it fluid, the right border around the outside goes out of place

https://jsfiddle.net/9jtxjb1s/

The HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                <body>
                    <div class="gridContainer clearfix">
                    <div id="LayoutDiv1">
                    <div id="container">
                        <header>
                            <h1>Heading 1</h1>
                            <h2>Heading 2</h2>
                        </header>
                        <nav>
                            <ul>    
                                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>  
                                <li><a href="link1.html">Link 1</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="gallery1.html">Gallery</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="link2.html">Link 2</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="gallery2.html">Gallery</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="link3.html">Link 3</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="gallery3.html">Gallery</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="link4.html">Link 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>

                        <section>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
                    <p>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>

                        </section>
                        <footer>
                            <p>&copy; Test</p>
                        </footer>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div> 
                </body>
                </html>
```

Styling CSS:

```
#container{
                    background:#228b22;
                    float:left;
                    border:1px solid #000000;
                    width:98%;
                }

                body {
                    font-family:Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    font-size:90%;
                    margin:20px auto;
                    text-align:center;
                    line-height:1.4em;
                    width:98%;
                    background:white;
                }

                header, section, article, footer,  nav{
                    padding:10px 20px 20px;
                    margin:10px;
                    float:left;
                    width:90%;
                    border:1px solid #000000;
                }

                header {
                    display:block;
                    position:relative;
                    text-align:left;
                }

                header h1 {
                    font-size:2.3em;
                    text-transform:none;
                    text-align:center;
                }

                header h2 {
                    margin:10px 0px 20px;
                    font-size:1.3em;
                    text-align:center;
                }

                nav {
                    float:left;
                    text-align:center;
                    display:block;
                }

                nav ul{
                    margin-left:15%;
                    padding:0;
                    list-style:none;
                    text-align:center;
                }

                nav ul li{
                    float:left;
                    width:150px;
                    height:30px;
                    line-height:30px;
                    text-align:center;
                    background:#4ea24e;
                    border:1px solid #000000;

                }

                nav ul li a{
                    text-decoration:none;
                    color:black;
                }

                nav ul li li{
                    background:#4ea24e;
                    color:#fff;
                    display:none;
                    float:left;
                    margin-left:-17.9%;
                }

                nav ul li li:hover{
                    background:#7ab97a;
                }

                nav ul li li a{
                    text-decoration:#8A5C2E;
                    color:#black;
                }
```

And finally, the fluid grid code:

```
        img, object, embed, video {
            max-width: 100%;
        }
        /* IE 6 does not support max-width so default to width 100% */
        .ie6 img {
            width:100%;
        }

        /* Mobile Layout: 480px and below. */

        .gridContainer {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 87.36%;
            padding-left: 1.82%;
            padding-right: 1.82%;
        }

        #LayoutDiv1 {
            clear: both;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
        }

        /* Tablet Layout: 481px to 768px. Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout. */

        @media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
        .gridContainer {
            width: 90.675%;
            padding-left: 1.1625%;
            padding-right: 1.1625%;
        }
        #LayoutDiv1 {
            clear: both;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
            border:1px solid #000000;
        }
        }

        /* Desktop Layout: 769px to a max of 1232px.  Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout and Tablet Layout. */

        @media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
        .gridContainer {
            width: 88.2%;
            max-width: 1232px;
            padding-left: 0.9%;
            padding-right: 0.9%;
            margin: auto;
        }
        #LayoutDiv1 {
            clear: both;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
        }
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what end result you're looking for. Your `#container` div has 98% width, so that's why it doesn't fill its containing div entirely (and why the border of the outer element is outside. Perhaps you meant to use 100% width on it?

Comment: I just realised and changed that. But there are still some problems. If you change the window size and me it smaller, the nav/header/section box widths begin to exceed that of the #container div and everything within the div is no longer centered

Answer (score 0):

I removed the 98% from #container element, seems okay now.

```
#container{
    background:#228b22;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #000000;
}
```

Check out the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9jtxjb1s/1/).

Comment: I took a look but when you adjust the window size, it still goes out

Answer (score 0):

You should not/do not need to set fixed widths to the inner elements, as they may overflow the outer container if there are paddings and margins set to them. Just leave the width to `auto` for header, section and nav, and control their width with `margin`.

Comment: I tried this it resulted in the boxes all being different sizes